# a value of type Node * cannot be used to initialize an entity of type Node *

Tags: c++, pointers, tree, intellisense, breadth-first-search

I'm writing a simple tree traversal procedure. I have a class for a node in the tree which holds the node's number, a vector of pointers to it's children and some data.

I pass this a pointer to a Node to some function which does BFS from that node.

```
class Node {
    public:
        int num;
        long long weight;
        long long tree_weight;
        vector<Node *> children;
        Node(int n, long long w) : num(n), weight(w) {}
};

long long tree_weight(Node * root, int n)
{
    vector<bool> visited(n);
    long long result=root->weight;
    queue<Node *> q;
    visited[root->num - 1] =true;

    Node * blah = root->children[0];
}
```

This compiles without issue. However, intellisense highlights the variable "root" and says the following: "a value of type Node * cannot be used to initialize an entity of type Node *". I don't understand this error message. What's going on?

Comment: Two variables, same name: `int n` / `Node * n`. And don't forget to return a value from your function.

Comment: `long long tree_weight;` then `long long tree_weight(Node * root, int n)` Do you want tree_weight to be a member variable or a free function? I say they are both wrong. You want it to be a member function.

Comment: I've noticed the naming error myself and edited the code and the post. The issue remains.

Comment: You fixed the problem @O'Neil mentioned but not the one I mentioned.

Comment: Of course a member function would be better choice, but it is not a syntax error strictly speaking, which is what my question is about

Comment: Remember that Intellisense is not always correct. It will have false positives.

Comment: I agree. It's just that when having a choice between blaming a well tested feature that has millions of users running on trivial code and blaming myself, I'd blame myself and ask stackoverflow ;) anyway, thank you all for helping. I suppose it's a false positive after all

Comment: Which line is it complaining about?

Comment: @Barmar this line: " Node * blah = root->children[0];"

Comment: The only potential problem with that line is if `children` is empty, but that's not what Intellisense is complaining about. I agree with the others that it's an Intellisense bug.